# My timer isn't stopping and I don't know the reason why - Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I have tried everything under the sun and I just can't figure out why my timer refuses to stop running.  If anyone could help, I would be so very grateful!  The cod is below:

```
package {
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Monster extends MovieClip
{

    var X:int;
    var Y:int;
    var dodge:Boolean = false;
    var myTween:Tween;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);// 1 second
    var alive:Boolean = true;
    var gameWidth = Main.stage.stageWidth;

    public function Monster(X:int, Y:int, whichMonster:Number):void
    {
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, dodgeAttack);
        if ( whichMonster == 1 )
        {
            myTimer.start();
            trace("Is it running "+myTimer.running);
            level_1(X, Y);
        }
        else if ( whichMonster == 2 )
        {
            myTimer.stop();
            removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,dodgeAttack);
            trace("Is it still running "+myTimer.running);
            level_2(X, Y);
        }
        else if ( whichMonster == 3 )
        {
            level_3(X, Y);
            trace("Is it running "+myTimer.running);
            myTimer.start();
        }
        else if ( whichMonster == 4 )
        {
            level_4(X, Y);
        }
    }

    public function level_1(X:int, Y:int):int
    {

        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        return X,Y;

    }
    public function level_2(X:int, Y:int):int
    {
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        //Just hardcode the tweens
        myTween = new Tween(this,"x",Strong.easeOut,this.x,500,1,true);
        myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
        return X,Y;
    }
    public function level_3(X:int, Y:int):int
    {
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        return X,Y;
    }

    public function level_4(X:int, Y:int):int
    {
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        return X,Y;
    }

    function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void
    {
        myTween.yoyo();
    }

    function dodgeAttack(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        var deflect:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

        if (deflect == 3)
        {
            this.gotoAndPlay(114);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("It Ran ");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out (whichMonster == 2) is true ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but ( whichMonster == 2 ) does run when it's called.  Weirdly, in that else if statement, placing the myTimer.running after myTimer.stop(), it says false.  And although removing the function dodgeAttack, it still somehow continues to run.

Comment: Does the"Is it still running " trace statement  triggered

Comment: Let me guess - you have several monsters on stage while testing this ? :) So you get traces from both monsters - 1 and 2. The whole timer code is in the constructor, so if you create a monster with whichMonster = 2 it does not even start the timer (so actually you should have the whole new timer(), addEventListener and myTimer.start() code only in your first if block

Comment: Yes, the still running statement is still triggered.

@Philarmon I had it the way you said, because it shouldn't be called every time class is called.  But even if I were to have it in the  level_1 function, it will continue to run once I stop it in the level_2 function.

Comment: there's no code in there that would stop the timer. All your timer.stop() in your code can only run when the timer has never started and none of those stop will ever run when the timer has started. It's a pure code logic problem, user tries to use a constructor to run logic that belong in member methods.

Comment: This is quite a mess of a code, some member are typed, some are not, some methods have modifier, some don't, there's 2 member called X,Y that are never ever set but in a bunch of methods parameters take the same name X,Y and nowhere the member seem to be referenced and so those member should go. Naming convention not used, variable name awful, It's a perfect code example if you want to show what should never be done in coding.

Comment: @BotMaster There is code that should stop the timer: myTimer.stop() I've also tried putting it in a member method itself.  I can upload what I've done before but I don't think you would be any help.  Thank you for showing me how rude the members of this site can be.

And before your rebuttal, just know my question was why wasn't my timer stopping, not if my code looks correct or up to your standards.  I'm learning, so please let me learn without negative statements like yours

Comment: I already answered in my first comment. Constructor run only once, in there you have if = start and if = stop so all that code can do is EITHER start the timer OR stop the timer (but in that case the timer has never even started).